# Is it possible to browse Safari bookmarks from within another iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, safari, bookmarks

I hope I overlooked something, but I haven't been able to find anything about reading/loading Safari bookmarks while using another application.. Is that possible? I want users to be able to copy existing bookmarks to a list in my application.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through the existing SDK or APIs but some threads suggest, through jailbreaking, you can access the file at:

> /var/mobile/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful but no, I'm not aware of any official method of importing Safari's bookmarks.